# C# Parameter count mismatch converting List to DataTable

Tags: c#, list, datatable

I am getting the exception mentioned in the title at the line of code

```
values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
```

and I am not sure what is causing this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);


    PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
    {

        var type = (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) : prop.PropertyType);

        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, type);
    }
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        var values = new object[Props.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
        }
        dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: What type of data are you passing in?  The method seems to work correctly with my tests.  For example, here it is with a basic collection: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6RWBpz

Comment: Found you a related article with a quick google of your subject line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143085/parameter-count-mismatch-when-getting-value-of-property-using-reflection

Comment: The data is a list of strings.

Comment: The dynamic type whatever it is can only be 1 value which is equal to T. I think your looping and setting of dataTable columns to multiple types from Props is incorrect. But it's a guess.

Answer (score 2):

If this line is throwing the exception

```
values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
```

...then it means you have a property that requires a parameter. In c#, the only type of property that takes a parameter is an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers). My guess is you should just exclude the indexer from the loop.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746188/propertyinfo-is-the-property-an-indexer) which tells you how to detect an indexer.

You can probably fix this by changing one line. Change this...

```
PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

...to this....

```
PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters == null))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually in the data that I passed into the method(a list of strings). It appeared that the GetValue() method was looking for an object. I created a class with a string property and changed my list type that was being passed in to the class and set the property in the class to the string that I was passing to the list in my foreach loop. Sorry if this doesn't make sense just trying to explain how I solved this, but the problem probably could have been solved a number of ways. Thanks, all.